# C# List.Remove(object);

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to remove an object from a list but it doesn't seem to be working.

In this scenario, I have an object called `shape` and a collection of objects called `shapes`.

I try to construct a new `List<Shape> shapesInSameColumn` by:

```
List<Shape> shapesInSameColumn = new List<Shape>();

foreach (var shape in shapes)
{
   if (fallingShape.ColumnNumber == shape.ColumnNumber)
   {
      shapesInSameColumn.Add(shape);
   }
}
```

What I want to do now, is remove just one object from the above collection. I do this by:

```
shapesInSameColumn.Remove(fallingShape);
```

fallingShape happens to be at index 1. But, when I perform the .Remove, it removes the object at index 0.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: shapesInSameColumn.RemoveAt(1);

Comment: The position of FallingShape will continuously change. I therefore cannot that.

Comment: Where you initialize fallingShape?

Comment: how you find FallingShape?

Comment: FallingShape is passed to this method via the MainGame class.

Comment: Does fallingshape has the same reference as one of the shape in shapes?

Comment: Ah I see where you're going with this. i think it does yes. Perhaps I can remove it from shapes first and then loop through shapes. I'll try that now.

Comment: I just tried that and it removed it from the source collection which is very bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (fallingShape.ColumnNumber == shape.ColumnNumber &&
     !object.ReferenceEquals(fallingShape,shape))
{
  shapesInSameColumn.Add(shape);
}
```

Instead of removing don't even add it to `shapesInSameColumn`

Here reference of fallingshape and shape is being compared. Now, there is a possibility that falling shape and shape both have same column number but different object. In that case add it else just not add it.

Comment: Genius! Absolute genius. Thank you very very very very very much!

Comment: Could you kindly translate that to English so that I understand what's going on please?

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
 shapesInSameColumn.RemoveAll(s => somecondition);
```

for example you need to remove shapes with ID equal to 1

```
shapesInSameColumn.RemoveAll(s => s.ID ==1);
```

Comment: Hmmmm ok. I shall try and perhaps add an ID.